# Reload SWF Object using Javascript (or JQuery) without re-loading whole page (after Ajax call)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, flash

The onreadstatechanged event fires ok after c# page on server completes database update. The asp.net page needs to re-load the embedded SWF Object without re-loading the whole page. Am currently Googling but was wondering if anyone could advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, so i put the swf on an ajax panel. on onreadystatechange 4/200 post the panel back and re-load from asmx which creates the config on demand from DB.